# Asus P8P67 Deluxe mobo: Network adapter off when PC is off; can't wake on LAN

Tags: motherboard, network-adapter, wake-on-lan, magic-packet

My Asus P8P67 Deluxe (rev 3) motherboard includes an Intel 82579 LAN controller. I have enabled wake-on-LAN with [these instructions](http://windows7-issues.blogspot.com/2011/03/wake-on-lan-wol-for-windows-7-made-easy.html) and it works from sleep, but it does not work when the PC is powered off. I heard the light on the network adapter needs to be on when the PC is off. I looked when the computer is off and the light is off. What can I do to fix this so I can get wake-on-LAN to work while the computer is off? I am using Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WOL is only supported for sleep and hibernate. In Windows 7 some network cards can manage it but not all.

Read: ["Wake on LAN" (WOL) behavior in Windows 8](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2776718/en-us) for the details.

Comment: In that case, is it possible for me to make my motherboard give the network adapter enough residual power for wake on LAN from complete off?

Comment: None that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone still uses this motherboard and couldn't solve the riddle, I found it is linked to AHCI Mode being enabled under the SATA Configuration.

I changed it to IDE mode and turned it off and the little LAN LED kept flashing, I've sent a WOL Packet from my phone and it woke up... I put it back into AHCI Mode (obviously Windows crashed without that) and when I saved and exited the BIOS the LAN Light no longer lit up. I then went into the Boot Priority List and added in the NIC in position 3 (after HDD & DVD-ROM, saved and shutdown and the little light was indeed blinking. I've sent a WOL Packet from my phone, it fired up, and went straight into Windows in AHCI mode with no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your necro knowledge despite this being of dwindling utility to most people! I'm surprised there are still people using this old hardware :)